# Showing room at contact

Tags: mysql

i have contact list in 'orang' table
[image]

when im login as baim (orang.id='38'), in mydevice will be display my contact from 'orang'table

```
select * from orang where id!='38'
```

[image]

how i can display 'room.id' in may contact from 'room' table ? 
(I want to display that in the red box)
roo.id will be display id from room table If there is a relationship between 2 contacts in the room. If there is no relationship between 2 contacts in the room will be display Null. 'pengirim' and 'penerima' field taken from orang.id
[image]

thank

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT room.id, orang.* FROM room, orang WHERE room.pengirim = orang.id and orang.id != 38
```

Comment: im sorry. This is not what I want to show. I have changed the question, please check

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```
select o.id, o.nama,o.poto, c.id as room from orang as o left join room as c
on (o.id=c.pengirim or o.id=c.penerima) and
(c.pengirim='38' or c.penerima='38')
where o.id!='38' group by o.id
```